# TimerTask / Handler with Delay getting called Multiple times

Tags: android, timer, android-handler

I need a delay for around 5 seconds. I have tried using Timer using below code :

```
            Timer myTimer = new Timer();
                myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                      Log.d(TAG,"Timer");
                    }

                }, 4000, 5000);
```

When i check logs, the Timer is getting printed **thrice**. If I change time, sometimes it gets printed in **log 4 times** as well.

I have tried using Handler as well like below :

```
   final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while (true) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(10000);
                                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                            Log.d(Utility.TAG,"Sleep::");

                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO: handle exception
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
```

But again the log is  **printing multiple times**. I just want to call my method once not multiple times. How can I achieve it ?

**EDIT**

used handler without thread as well like below :

```
 final Handler h = new Handler();
               final int delay = 3000; //milliseconds

                h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        //do something
                        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
                        Log.d(Utility.TAG,"Sleep ::");
                    }
                }, delay);
```

But again, Log is getting printed **thrice**

Comment: just use a `Handler` without any thread

Comment: where is `final Handler h = new Handler();` in your code? add `Log.d(Utility.TAG,"Start ::");` to see when it is called

Comment: @pskink i have edited the question. You can see, i have defined the final Handler h above. It is getting called in click listener of an image.

Comment: if you are calling `h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){` three times you will get the results like yours, just delete any pending Runnables `removeCallbacks(Runnable r)` before posting new ones

Comment: @pskink thanks a lot, Your last comment helped me in fixing the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Your third approach (no `Timer`, no `Thread`) is the closest to being correct.  It's printing multiple times because the `Runnable` is re-posting itself every time it runs.  If you only want it to run once, remove this line from the `run()` method:

```
h.postDelayed(this, delay);
```

Comment: I have removed that, but still its getting called mutiple times.